# I want to merge duplicate cells in a dataframe and display in html by knit option

Tags: r

Lets say I have a dataframe like this 
[image: Input Table]

I tried this

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE,   warning=F, results="axis"}
df<- read.csv("test.csv",header = T)
library(dplyr)
df<- df%>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month,Name)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(Count=n())

df$Type[duplicated(df$Type)] <- " "

df$Type <- sapply(df$Type, as.character)
df$Type[is.na(df$Type)] <- " "

library(xtable)
print(xtable(df),type="html")

```
````

I removed the duplicates but I want to merge the cells as in rowspan to display in html and knit like this .

[image: Output Table]

Comment: Some usable data would be useful to help us help you. [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)